# Parse plist file and get value for key

Tags: ios, xml, plist, nsdictionary

I have this file below:

[image]

I have a question, how can I get url value from this plist file.

I have convert this file to a NSDictionary and it has all keys and values.

I've added this line to check how it works

```
 NSLog(@"%@", [[[[source objectForKey:@"Root"] objectForKey:@"updates"] objectForKey:@"Item 0"] objectForKey:@"url"]);
```

but it returns (null) instead of someurl1.

source - this is my NSDictionary instance variable.

This log for my NSDictionary object

```
(NSDictionary *) $1 = 0x0ab38b60 {
    plist =     {
        dict =         {
            array =             {
                dict =                 (
                                        {
                        integer = 4;
                        key =                         (
                            id,
                            url,
                            compression
                        );
                        string = "http://someurl1";
                        true = "";
                    },
                                        {
                        integer = 5;
                        key =                         (
                            id,
                            url,
                            compression
                        );
                        string = "http://someurl2";
                        true = "";
                    }
                );
            };
            key = updates;
        };
        version = "1.0";
    };
}
```

Comment: You can't access the items of arrays by `objectForKey:`. **Item 0** can be accessed by `objectAtIndex:`.

Comment: thanks for response. I tried  NSLog(@"%@", [[[[source objectForKey:@"Root"] objectForKey:@"updates"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"url"]); but it still output null

Comment: What does `[source objectForKey:@"Root"]` output? You may not need to get that object by name - it is, after all, the root object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
for (NSDictionary *item in [source objectForKey:@"updates"]) {

    NSLog(@"%@", [item objectForKey:@"url"]);
}
```

Note that 'Root' isn't a key, it's just the way Xcode displays the plist. And you need to loop over an array, again 'Item 0' is just the way it's displayed in the IDE.

Comment: I have updated my question with NSLog for my NSDictionary. Maybe some problems with keys.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", [source objectForKey:@"updates"]); also return null

Comment: The log for your dictionary bears zero resemblance to the Xcode screenshot. You loaded a different plist or how did you load it?

Comment: I ve tried this NSDictionary *rootDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PListFile" ofType:@"plist"]]; and it works. in any case thanks for help. this is my mistake with getting dictionary

Answer (score 2):

Very well.

Try this code.

```
NSDictionary *rootDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PListFile" ofType:@"plist"]];
NSLog(@"%@", [[[rootDictionary objectForKey:@"updates"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"url"]);
```